# Задача с datepicker в js. Разная стоимость по разным датам

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Подскажите правильную реализацию.

Есть отель. 
С 25 мая по 10 июня стоимость номера 2500.
С 10 июня по 20 юиня стоимость номера 3000
С 20 июня по 20 августа стоимость номера 4000.

Собственно нужно просчитать стоимость в зависимости от того, какие даты выбрал пользователь. Например, если я заказываю номер с 7 по 11 июня, то стоимость будет (10-7) * 2500 + (11-10) * 3000 = 10500

Пока что получилась кутерьма.

Есть уже массив с датой

```
var arrdate1 = date1.split('.'); // [2019, 06, 22]
```

Получаю 2 даты

```
date1 = new Date(date1); // приводим в формат даты ('2018/06/22')
date2 = new Date(date2);
```

Создаю даты-границы изменения цены

```
 var date5 = new Date ('2019/06/10'); // Дата когда изменяется цена
 var date6 = new Date ('2019/06/20'); // дата изменения цены
```

Ну и тут полная фигня

```
  // Эти переменные нужны в случае, если клиент проживает в несколько периодов.
  var days1 = 0; // Количество дней по одному курсу
  var days2 = 0; // Количество дней по второму курсу
  var pays1 = 0; // Оплата за 1-й период
  var pays2 = 0; // Оплата за второй период


  if (arrdate1[1] == "06" && arrdate1[2] < 10) { // Если месяц июнь, и дата заезда меньше 10, то
  var start = Math.floor(date1.getTime() / (3600 * 24 * 1000)); 
  var middle = Math.floor(date5.getTime() / (3600 * 24 * 1000));
  var end = Math.floor(date2.getTime() / (3600 * 24 * 1000)); 
  days1 = middle - start; // Это дни первого периода.
  days2 = end - middle; // Это дни второго периода.
  pays1 = days1 * 2500;
  pays2 = days2 * 3000;
                }
```

Как бы оно работает сейчас в таком формате. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что это говнокод.

А если человек живет с 8 по 22 июня, у него получается вообще 3 периода проживания по разным ценам.

Подскажите, как это все сделать правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде работоспособно

```js
let datePriceArray = [
{from:'2018/05/25',to:'2018/06/10',price:2500},
{from:'2018/06/10',to:'2018/06/20',price:3000},
{from:'2018/06/20',to:'2018/08/20',price:4000},
]

function getPrice(from,to){
  let price = 0;
  from = new Date(from);
  to = new Date(to);
  datePriceArray.forEach(dp=>{
    let dpFrom = new Date(dp.from);
    let dpTo = new Date(dp.to);
    // начинается в этом периоде
    if(from > dpFrom && to > dpTo)
    price += dp.price*getDays(dpTo - from);
    // начинает и заканчивается в этом периоде
    if(from > dpFrom && to < dpTo)
    price += dp.price*getDays(to - from);
    // заканчивается в этом периоде
    if(from < dpFrom && to > dpFrom && to < dpTo)
    price += dp.price*getDays(to - dpFrom);
    // занимает весь период
    if(from < dpFrom && to > dpTo)
    price += dp.price*getDays(dpTo - dpFrom);  
  });
  
  console.log(price)
}

function getDays(mileseccond){
  return mileseccond/1000/3600/24;
}

getPrice('2018/06/7','2018/06/11');
```

Comment: Очень круто, спасибо. Я не ожидал, что кто-то даст готовое решение, думал, что подтолкнут только.

Comment: Непонятно только 

  datePriceArray.forEach(dp=>{

    let dpFrom = new Date(dp.from); // присваиваем переменной dpFrom значение свойства объекта?

Как так, ведь dp - это название функции, а не имя объекта.

Comment: @Amigo9876 Отклонил вашу правку: нарушает исходный замысел автора, вам для начала стоило бы у него уточнить. Я понимаю, что вопрос ваш - но это не повод править чужой ответ: можете либо написать автору ответа предложение поправить и подождать, пока согласится или оформить новый ответ рядом.

Comment: @A K. Извините, я просто не понял, как это делается. 
@Gs D. Там в первых двух условиях не хватает (from < dpTo).